# Is it possible to include the execution month in the table name when CREATE with Athena's presto sql?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

If the execution date is today, this month is July, so I want to include the month after the table name.
I want to put category_table202107 even the month after the table name, Is it possible to include the execution month in the table name when CREATE with Athena's presto sql?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to 'calculate' the name of a table in the `CREATE TABLE` command.

Instead, you should do that in whatever program is sending the `CREATE TABLE` command to Amazon Athena.